# Upgrading prestashop with 1-click upgrade error

Tags: symfony, prestashop

Please, someone should help me.

I was doing an upgrade from 1.7.5 to 1.7.8 and ran into Prestashop error below:

> Could not extract
> vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Tests/DependencyInjection/Fixtures/xml/profiler.xml
> from backup, the destination might not be writable.

PHP is 7.4

Comment: Have you used sudo when upgrading ?

Comment: no. please, can you share the code, i am new to coding

Comment: don't think he can run something, 1-click upgrade is a plugin, he is trying to lunch the upgrade from PS's admin interface, @wincloud right ?

Comment: if you have FTP or SSH access, try de change the access rights (chmod) of the indicated folder (vendor I think)

Comment: @Sami thanks alot. I have resolve the issue

Comment: @wincloud How did you fix the problem ? You should explain it to help the community :)